# How does the Amazon CloudWatch work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xen

Suppose I have an EC2 instance, which I understood is a VM instance. So if I enable CloudWatch for this EC2 instance, should this monitoring capabilitiy offered by CloudWatch added into my EC2 instance, or it is just running in the hypervisor like XEN?

Thanks.

Comment: From [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=156643&#156643), someone mentioned it is done inside the hypervisor. Anymore details will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is monitored at the hypervisor layer. Aamazon generally will not look into the instance at VM layer so they can't monitor some feature such as memroy usage at the VM.

Comment: To do memory, or other parameters you'll need to do a custom metric parameter from within the instance as described here: http://www.lustforge.com/2012/07/22/custom-cloudwatch-metric-tutorial-freememory-and-cron/

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch monitoring is always enabled by default for every EC2 instance at 5-min granularity. What you can enable is detailed monitoring which means you get 1-min observation granularity and aggregate metrics. Default monitoring at 5-min level is free, but detailed monitoring costs money.

Out-of-the-box CloudWatch metrics are measured at hypervisor level and you do not need to do anything to turn them on. See more info on what metrics are available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html

Things like memory utilization and disk space can't be measured at hypervisor level so CloudWatch distributes a simple package with scripts that can be installed on the instance (Linux or Windows.) Those scripts report the data as custom metrics which also costs money. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html